# microsoft bot Framework giving error-'await' cannot be used as an identifier within an async method or lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, botframework

I am trying to create a chatbot and tumbled upon this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-a-simple-bot-application-using-microsoft-bot-framew/). Followed the instruction and it gave an error

> 'await' cannot be used as an identifier within an async method or lambda expression

My complete .cs code :

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace chatbot.Dialogs
{
 [Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // calculate something for us to return
        int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

        // return our reply to the user
        await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
}
```

I am new to this Bot application , so if I miss anything do let me know.

Thanks

Comment: code is correct can you please share the complete .cs file or dialog

Comment: added complete code for .cs file

Answer (score 1):

you need to put:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
```

in place of

```
 public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
```

and replace

```
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

it will look like:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace chatbot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);


        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            // calculate something for us to return
            int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

            // return our reply to the user
            await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

feel free to revert in case of more help required

Comment: Why would he do that if await is not used in `StartAsync`?

Comment: I tried that however still gives me same error on `await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");`

Comment: try using this   `await context.PostAsync("You sent "+activity.Text+" which was "+length+" characters");`

Comment: thanks , no error now, however when I run the emulator and send text it says `Couldn't send retry`

Comment: great .. can you mark the answer correct .  cheers and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

It looks prefect on your code, I don't think the issue was raised by your code. And I found that the tutorial you referred was post 2016 and which may be out of date. Maybe the structure/ code of the template has changed which raised your issue.

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart for the official quick started for .Net, and which will be updated in time.

And currently, all the referencs in the sample:

```
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Chronic.Signed" version="0.3.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bot.Builder" version="3.11.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bot.Connector" version="3.11.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" version="1.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net46" />
```

Comment: I have "Microsoft.Bot.Builder" version="3.8.0.0" and "Microsoft.Bot.Connector" version="3.8.0.0" as I am runnign VS 2012 and  `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />`

Comment: You can update the bot builder to latest version in nuget management tool.

Comment: The Bot Builder SDK for .NET requires .NET Framework 4.6 or newer. If you are adding the SDK to an existing project targeting a lower version of the .NET Framework, you will need to update your project to target .NET Framework 4.6 first. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-overview for details

Comment: I upgraded to 4.6 but zstill same `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>`

Comment: How you update the project's .net version? Right click project name -> properties ->in Application section change the Target framework droplist to `4.6` -> rebuild the solution in VS ?

Comment: yes, I downloaded and installed .Net framework 4.6 Target Pack aand set target framework to 4.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159640/discussion-between-gary-liu-msft-and-mark).